# dafny i want to check if i can enhance this code

Tags: dafny

```
datatype Tree<T> = Leaf | Node(Tree<T>, Tree<T>, T)//Declare Datatype Tree which can either be a leaf or a node; Node can agian be defined as 2 trees and 1 split point/node
datatype List<T> = Nil | Cons(T, List<T>)//Declare datatype List as either Nil or as Cons of Tree and a list
```

//Main purpose of this script is to prove the flattening of tree that results in a tree contains same element as all the elements of a tree
//Flattening of a tree meaning simply transversing each node of a tree and getting all nodes/ last leaf in a list format.

//Below function takes 2 lists xs and ys as input and returns a list whihc is combination of 2 input lists

```
function append<T>(xs:List<T>, ys:List<T>):List decreases  xs

{
  //Match input1 if it is Nil i.e. end of list/no list then return the right remaning element or if it is of format Cons(element1,remaining list) then return
  //Cons(element1,recursively call append with remaining list and one first element)
  //So whilst reaching last Nil element, we will get appended list of all the elements.
    match(xs) 
        case Nil => ys
        case Cons(element1, rem_list) =>  Cons(element1, append(rem_list, ys))
}
```

//Below function takes 1 List and 1 element as input and returns a boolean True or False depending on whether the element is in the list or not

```
function listContains<T>(xs:List<T>, element:T):bool
 decreases  xs
{
  //Match List1: If input parameter 1 is a list of format Cons(z,zs), and if z i.e. first element of list == input parameter 2 then return True
  //Else Continue recursively calling same function until the element condition is met or the list is exhausted. Then return True
    match(xs)
        case Cons(element1, rem_list) => element1==element || listContains(rem_list, element) 
        case Nil => false
}
```

//Below function takes 1 Tree and 1 element as input and returns a boolean True or False depending on whether the element is in the Tree or not

```
function treeContains<T>(tree:Tree<T>, element:T):bool decreases  tree

{
  //Match Tree1: If input parameter 1 is a Leaf,return false implying the element is not present in the Tree
  // If it is a node then reduce node into 2 trees and keep checking each of the sub-trees contains the node
  //Continue recursively calling same function until Node is same as element or the Tree is exhausted. Then return True
    match(tree)
    case Leaf() => false
    case Node(tree1, tree2, CurrentNode) => treeContains(tree1, element) || treeContains(tree2, element)
}
```

//Below function takes 1 Tree as input and returns a list which is obtained by appending each node as an element of a list

```
function flatten<T>(tree:Tree<T>):List <T>
{
  //Match If the input is a LEaf return Nil or keep on returning and appending CurrentNode with the result of recursively callling faltten function.
  //Hence this will in turn result the complete list which constitutes each node as an element.
    match(tree)
    case Leaf() =>  Nil
    case Node(tree1, tree2, CurrentNode) => Cons(CurrentNode,append(flatten(tree1),flatten(tree2)))

}
```

```
ghost method sameElements<T>(tree:Tree<T>, element:T)
{
    match(tree)
    case Leaf() =>
    //If the Tree is a simple element the proof might not be needed
    //However if we have trees then we check the result of treecontains and listcontains function if that is true it prooves the thesis.
    case Node(tree11,tree2,CurrentNode) =>
    calc {
       treeContains(tree, element)
        == 
      listContains(flatten(tree),element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the code formatter to format your code so its more easily readable.

Comment: okey thanks can you check again

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but note that the `sameElements` method does not actually prove the two functions equivalent. The `calc` statement should have a semicolon after the first line. Otherwise, you have a `calc` statement of length 1, which doesn't prove anything.